# server rendering with react-router v4 and express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I'm trying to set up server-side rendering with the newest version of react-router v.4. I followed this tutorial https://react-router.now.sh/ServerRouter.

I get following error when I refresh browser: **Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.**

my **routes.jsx** file:

```
export default () =>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Match pattern="/" component={Home} />
    <Match pattern="/about" component={About} />
    <Miss component={NotFound} />
  </div>;
```

and in **index.jsx** I'm rendering app

```
import  BrowserRouter from 'react-router';    
import Routes from './routes';

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter> <Routes /> </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Now as server I'm using **express.js**. Here is my configuration:

```
import  Routes  from '../routes';

server.use((req, res) => {
  const context = createServerRenderContext();
  let markup = renderToString(
    <ServerRouter location={req.url} context={context} > <Routes /> </ServerRouter>);
  const result = context.getResult();

  if (result.redirect) {
    res.writeHead(301, {
      Location: result.redirect.pathname,
    });
    res.end();
  } else {
    if (result.missed) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      markup = renderToString(
        <ServerRouter location={req.url} context={context}> <Routes /> </ServerRouter>);
    }
    res.write(markup);
    res.end();
  }
});
```

I didn't find any tutorial for server-rendering with this version of react-routes except official. 
Can anyone help me what I'm doing wrong ? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Solved !**

First problem was that I had spaces around `<Routes />` tag.

Correct solution:

```
<ServerRouter location={req.url} context={context}><Routes /></ServerRouter>);
```

Second problem was in included `<Header />`  tag in routes.jsx file.

I had the following error **(Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `StatelessComponent`**)

File Header.jsx contained the following line of code:

```
import Link  from 'react-router';
```

**Correct solution:** (I forgot to put curly brackets ):

```
 import { Link } from 'react-router';
```

Answer (score 1):

The big issue is that the`<BrowserRouter>` is only expected to have one child, so you should wrap it's children in a `div`. This is done so that React Router is environment agnostic (you can't render a `div` in React Native, so RR expects you to include the appropriate wrapper).

```
export default () =>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Match pattern="/" component={Home} />
      <Match pattern="/about" component={About} />
      <Miss component={NotFound} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>;
```

As a secondary issue, you are including the `<BrowserRouter>` in your `<App>` component, so it will be rendered on the server. You do not want this. Only the `<ServerRouter>` should be rendered on the server. You should move the `<BrowserRouter>` further up your client side component hierarchy to avoid this.

```
// App
export default () =>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Match pattern="/" component={Home} />
    <Match pattern="/about" component={About} />
    <Miss component={NotFound} />
  </div>;

// index.js
render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I fixed this issues but still get same error.

Comment: Could you update your question with the current state of your code?

Comment: I updated my code and remove App.jsx file because it wasn't neccesary to use it anymore.

Comment: What is the full error? Does it reference a specific component or a line in your code?

Comment: Remove the spaces from around your `<Routes />` component. Those are being interpreted as spaces when your JSX is being converted to `React.createElement` expressions.

Comment: probably that was problem but anyway  I get another error

Comment: Another thing to check is the `<Route>...</Route>` in the component(s) wrapped within the Router. I'd screwed up and had a dummied-up component's JSX including

    <Item.Header>
      <Route to="#">The Wonderful Title</Route>
    </Item.Header>

When I replaced the line to read `<Route to='#'><span>The Wonderful Title</span></Route>`, all was well.

Answer (score 1):

because `BrowserRouter` doesn't exist on `react-router`, try install and import it from `react-router-dom`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answers listed above is outdated. As of today, the official **[react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)** docs suggest using [StaticRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/StaticRouter.md) instead of *ServerRouter* for server side rendered apps.

A fantastic documentation can be found [here.](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md)

Answer (score -1):

For anybody coming later, Ryan Florence has added a snippet of how to accomplish this.

[SSR in React Router v4](https://gist.github.com/ryanflorence/efbe562332d4f1cc9331202669763741)

```
// routes.js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Home,
    exact: true
  },
  {
    path: '/gists',
    component: Gists
  },
  {
    path: '/settings',
    component: Settings
  }
]

// components
class Home extends React.Component {

  // called in the server render, or in cDM
  static fetchData(match) {
    // going to want `match` in here for params, etc.
    return fetch(/*...*/)
  }

  state = {
    // if this is rendered initially we get data from the server render
    data: this.props.initialData || null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // if rendered initially, we already have data from the server
    // but when navigated to in the client, we need to fetch
    if (!this.state.data) {
      this.constructor.fetchData(this.props.match).then(data => {
        this.setState({ data })
      })
    }
  }

  // ...
}

// App.js
const App = ({ routes, initialData = [] }) => (
  <div>
    {routes.map((route, index) => (
      // pass in the initialData from the server for this specific route
      <Route {...route} initialData={initialData[index]} />
    ))}
  </div>
)

// server.js
import { matchPath } from 'react-router'

handleRequest((req, res) => {
  // we'd probably want some recursion here so our routes could have
  // child routes like `{ path, component, routes: [ { route, route } ] }`
  // and then reduce to the entire branch of matched routes, but for
  // illustrative purposes, sticking to a flat route config
  const matches = routes.reduce((matches, route) => {
    const match = matchPath(req.url, route.path, route)
    if (match) {
      matches.push({
        route,
        match,
        promise: route.component.fetchData ?
          route.component.fetchData(match) : Promise.resolve(null)
      })
    }
    return matches
  }, [])

  if (matches.length === 0) {
    res.status(404)
  }

  const promises = matches.map((match) => match.promise)

  Promise.all(promises).then((...data) => {
    const context = {}
    const markup = renderToString(
      <StaticRouter context={context} location={req.url}>
        <App routes={routes} initialData={data}/>
      </StaticRouter>
    )

    if (context.url) {
      res.redirect(context.url)
    } else {
      res.send(`
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
          <div id="root">${markup}</div>
          <script>DATA = ${escapeBadStuff(JSON.stringify(data))}</script>
        </html>
      `)
    }
  }, (error) => {
    handleError(res, error)
  })
})

// client.js
render(
  <App routes={routes} initialData={window.DATA} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```