# server side rendering with react router v4

Tags: reactjs, express, server-side-rendering, react-router-v4

[Following this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41486804/server-rendering-with-react-router-v4-and-express-js)

I tried to set up server rendering with react-router-v4

my **routes.js** file :

```js
var React = require('react');
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Appa from './components/app.js';
import Welcome from './components/welcome.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route,Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

export default () =>
<Router>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Appa} />
    <Route path="/home" component={Welcome} />
  </div>
  </Router>;
```

**server.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server';
import { match, RoutingContext,ServerRouter, createServerRenderContext } from 'react-router';
import Routes from './app/routes.js';
var express  = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(function(req,res,next) {
const context = createServerRenderContext();
  let markup = renderToString(
    <ServerRouter location={req.url} context={context} > <Routes /> </ServerRouter>);
  const result = context.getResult();

  if (result.redirect) {
    res.writeHead(301, {
      Location: result.redirect.pathname,
    });
    res.end();
  } else {
    if (result.missed) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      markup = renderToString(
        <ServerRouter location={req.url} context={context}> <Routes /> </ServerRouter>);
    }
    res.write(markup);
    res.end();
  }

});

app.get('*', function(req,res,next){
 
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname ,'/dist/index.html'));
   
});
```

Whenever my app routes to /home it  takes alot of time to load and eventually shows cannot get /home  Please help me identifying the mistake in code

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that you have your callback parameters `req` and `res` switched around.  The callback has a signature of `function(req, res, next)`. Try moving your use function above the declaration of the app.all callback.

Comment: that was silly from my side
but after correcting this  i am getting same output
 cannot get /home 
.... with both app.use() and app.get() this is not working ..

Comment: Thanks @stephen
I tried again with ur suggestions but i am still not getting /home and i edited my question with current code ,

It is taking ages to load the /home page and finally it is giving cannot GET /home
and i am getting console.log(req.url) output as /home